# How to show textview is clickable?

Tags: android, textview

I have five text view and all are clickable, how to give them a visual effect so that the user can identify it is clickable. I already dropped the idea of underlining the textview, so is there any other way available.

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#94FFFF" /> <!-- pressed -->

     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#94FFFF" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#5C9E70" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Comment: what kind of visual effect would you like to have?

Comment: i dont know exactly, but may be some kind of emboss ...or anything best you can suggest

Comment: Are you setting it to be clickable in code?

Comment: Well lets just say you could set tex color to gray to indicate its not clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite is to draw a circle around the TextView and actually make it a button that contains the style elements of a TextView;

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    style="@android:style/Widget.TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/but_bg" />
```

where but_bg is an .xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="820"
            android:startColor="#df242424"
            android:centerColor="#df343434"
            android:endColor="#da444444"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:radius="7dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="8dp"
            android:top="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp" />
       </shape>
       </item>
</selector>
```

Using the radial colors in there you can also make it look more plastic. This then looks like [image: button]

You can also apply an xml drawable to a layout, in case you want to keep the TextView. Then you just wrap it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/but_bg"
[...]>
    <TextView 
       [...] />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I just realized that a `Button` basically is a `TextView` subclass with another style. I haven't tested this with `TextView` tags but it should work the same way if someone wants to keep it a `TextView`.

Comment: if i want to draw a circle like this around the textview and i dont want to make it a button...is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StateListDrawable`. Just create a xml file with `selector` as a root tag and assign it as `textColor` or `backgroundColor` to your `TextView` depending on the behavior you want.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
       android:state_activated="true"
       android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_img" />
    <item
       android:state_activated="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_img" />
    <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/normal_img" />
</selector>
```

Also you have to make yout `TextView` clickable by setting the `android:clickable` attribute to `true`.